# python form a dict from a file

Tags: python, dictionary

anybody point me to right direction how to form a dict from following file? 
#file

```
00688    value_disg            test4 <br>
00689    value_disg            test4 <br>
0068A    value_disg            test3 <br>
0068B    value_disg            test2 <br>
0068F    value_disg            test1 <br>
00690    value_disg            test1 <br>
```

What I need is to form a dict from column 3 containing values from column 1 and 2. 
Example:

```
test1 = [0068F    value_disg, 0068F    value_disg] <br>
test2 = [0068B    value_disg] <br>
test4 = [ 00688    value_disg, 00689    value_disg] <br>
...
```

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far? you need to read the file line by line and then prepare the dictionary after splitting the values in the line.

Comment: I managed to form with column 1 (its unique value) but struggling to create in a optimal way from column 3. file = 'test.txt'
results = {}
with open(file,'r') as f:
   lines = f.read()
   for line in lines.split('\n'):
      line = re.split('\s+', line)
      results[line[0]] = [line[1:]]

print(results)

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        val1, val2, val3 = line.split()
        d[val3].append((val1, val2))
```

Here, did ur hw

Comment: Thanks GQV,! Why I cant make it so simple :).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are overriding the dictionary every time where as you need to append to the result:

```
output = dict()
with open('Odata.txt', 'r') as infile: # open file
    for line in infile: # reading line by line
        values = line.strip().split() # splitting the line as list
        if values[2] not in output.keys():
             output[values[2]] = [' '.join(values[:2])] # create the list first time 
        else:
             output[values[2]].append(' '.join(values[:2])) # append to the list

    print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'test4': ['00688 value_disg', '00689 value_disg'], 'test3': ['0068A value_disg'], 'test2': ['0068B value_disg'], 'test1': ['0068F value_disg', '00690 value_disg']}
```

You can use `setdefault()` to club `if-else` into a single line:

```
output = dict()
with open('Odata.txt', 'r') as infile: # open file
    for line in infile: # reading line by line
        values = line.strip().split() # splitting the line as list
        output.setdefault(values[2], []).append(' '.join(values[:2])) # update the dictionary
```